# Nivo-Slider for custom Image Bullets

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to create custom image to replace the “numbers” of Control-Nav.
The result would be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG9vo.jpg)

Been  trying out various different ways to modify the nivo css but it's not working.
Adding the follow options doesn't work.

```
.nivo-controlNav a:nth-child(1) {
    background-image:url(‘image/banner_button.png’);
}
.nivo-controlNav a:nth-child(2) {
    background-image:url(‘image/banner_button2.png’);
}
```

Neither do these.

```
.nivo-controlNav a {
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:url('image/banner_button2.png');
}
```

The image path works as i have sucessfully display images out on my test site.
I would only need 2 bullets as i have 2 banner images to display only.

Is there any solution to this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably have to be more specific: .nivo-controlNav > a.nivo-control {style...} & .nivo-controlNav > a.nivo-control.active {style...}

Comment: @Christina Can you explain further? I came across this site, <http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-make-unique-bullets-for-nivo-slider/> and tried using it with no avail.

Comment: The css has to be more specific. I've styled the bullets to be as you described using CSS and it works fine. Open up their css, see how they specify the styles on the bullets and then use their specificity.

Comment: @Christina can you show me how is it done? i tried but i just can't make it appear. From my understanding, .nivo-controlNav and its childs are the one that make how the bullets appear. Am i right?

Comment: Why don't you just change one of their themes? Are you sure that that's your image path from your CSS directory? Usually, mine is one out assets/css/ and assets/images so the path to my images in css is ../images/filename.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and i guess i'll post the solution out to help anyone facing this problem.
The trick is to **Import a theme**, in my case i'll use the default theme.

This is my following codes to add the nivoslider in html

```
   <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"  style="margin-top:-17px;border:none;padding:0px; z-index:1">
     <img src="./image/banner1.jpg" alt="" />
     <img src="./image/banner2.jpg" alt="" />
   </div>
  </div>
```

And adding this line to the default theme css.

```
.nivo-controlNav a:nth-child(1) {
background-image:url(banner_button.jpg);
}
.nivo-controlNav a:nth-child(2) {
background-image:url(banner_button2.jpg);
}
```

Hope that helps. Special Thanks to @Christina !